# How to set java target and source version when using gradle maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, maven-plugin

I am using gradle 3.5 and maven plugin for gradle.

I have a task to generate the pom.xml , the pom generated is wrong due to source and target version of java.

This generated a pom.xml for 1.5 (wrong):

```
task createPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'com.domain.api'
            artifactId 'gs-gradle'
            version '0.1.0'
            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

This make the `gradle makePom` task fail:

```
task createPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'com.domain.api'
            artifactId 'gs-gradle'
            version '0.1.0'
            build {
                plugins {
                    plugin {
                        groupId 'org.apache.maven.plugins'
                        artifactId 'maven-compiler-plugin'
                        version '3.7.0'
                        configuration {
                            source '1.8'
                            target '1.8'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

This is the output error when adding the `build` object :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':createPom'.
> No such property: _SCRIPT_CLASS_NAME_ for class: org.apache.maven.model.Model

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Do you get an error messages from gradle when you try and build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the target and source issue :

```
pom {
    project {
        groupId 'com.domain.api'
        artifactId 'gs-gradle'
        version '0.1.0'
        properties {
            project {
                build {
                    sourceEncoding 'UTF-8'
                }
            }
            maven {
                compiler {
                    source '1.8'
                    target '1.8'
                }
            }
        }

        inceptionYear '2008'
        licenses {
            license {
                name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I was able to set properties.

**If you really need to customize the `build`**, you won't be able to declare it the same way because of the plugin in charge of it. This is how you can do:

```
pom {
    project {
        groupId 'com.domain.api'
        artifactId 'gs-gradle'
        version '0.1.0'
        properties {
            project {
                build {
                    sourceEncoding 'UTF-8'
                }
            }
            maven {
                compiler {
                    source '1.8'
                    target '1.8'
                }
            }
        }

        inceptionYear '2008'
        licenses {
            license {
                name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }
    }
}.withXml {
    asNode().appendNode('build').appendNode('plugins').with {
        appendNode('plugin').with {
            appendNode('groupId', 'org.springframework.boot')
            appendNode('artifactId', 'spring-boot-maven-plugin')
            appendNode('version', "${springBootVersionDef}")
            appendNode('executions').appendNode('execution').appendNode('goals').with {
                appendNode('goal', 'repackage')
            }
        }
        appendNode('plugin').with {
            appendNode('groupId', 'org.apache.maven.plugins')
            appendNode('artifactId', 'maven-jar-plugin')
            appendNode('version', "3.0.2")
            appendNode('configuration').appendNode('archive').appendNode('manifest').with {
                appendNode('addClasspath', "true")
                appendNode('classpathPrefix', "lib/")
                appendNode('mainClass', "com.domain.api.Application")
            }
        }
    }
}.writeTo("pom.xml")
```